# Rubaxa-Sortable Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': '>*' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drag-and-drop, vuejs2, rubaxa-sortable

I am using vuejs and [Rubaxa Sortable](http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/) JavaScript library. The sortable is working fine with `<ul><li>` but with table-rows, it's giving this error when I rearrange by drag-and-drop.

```
Sortable.min.js:3 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': '>*' is not a valid selector.
```

I am using Vue.js v2.5.13 and Rubaxa Sortable v1.7.0.

```js
Vue.directive('sortable', {
  inserted: function (el, binding) {
    var sortable = new Sortable(el, binding.value || {});
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      items: [{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3},{id: 4},{id: 5}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    reorder ({oldIndex, newIndex}) {
      const movedItem = this.items.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0]
      this.items.splice(newIndex, 0, movedItem)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/RubaXa/Sortable/c35043730c22ec173bac595346eb173851aece20/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>With List</h2>
  <ul v-sortable="{onEnd: reorder}">
    <li v-for="i in items" :key="i.id">{{ i.id }}</li>
  </ul>

  <hr/>

  <h2>With Table</h2>
  <table v-sortable="{onEnd: reorder}">
    <tr v-for="i in items" :key="i.id">
      <td>{{ i.id }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  {{ items }}

</div>
```

Comment: I was able to fix it by: 1. Putting `v-sortable` on the `tbody` (needs to be added inside the table), not the `table`, and 2. Including the non-minified version of Sortable.js. See https://jsfiddle.net/5ac7zxmp/26/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `<table>` cannot contain table rows (`<tr>`). The structure of a table is like this.

```
<table>
   <thead></thead>
   <tbody></tbody>
   <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

So when we write html table like this,

```
<table>
   <tr>First Row</tr>
   <tr>Second Row</tr>
</table>
```

The browser automatically inserts all rows inside `<tbody>` and renders it like this.

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>First Row</tr>
      <tr>Second Row</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

So table rows are not direct child of `<table>`, rather they are children of `<tbody>`. So generate your table rows inside `<tbody>` and add v-sortable to that `<tbody>`.

```
<table>
   <tbody v-sortable="{onEnd: reorder}">  <!-- v-sortable here -->
      <tr v-for="i in items" :key="i.id">
         <td>{{ i.id }}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

And the minified version of **Sortable** has a bug, they somehow got rid of a `try-catch` block when the minified it causing it to fail when anything other than `<ul><li>` is sorted. So untill they fix it, use the development i.e uncompressed version of **Sortable**.